# Remove array when timestamp is equal to now

Tags: javascript, timestamp

Let's say I have this array

```
[
  {
    "ytChannel": "xxx",
    "startAmount": "1",
    "minGrowth": "2",
    "maxGrowth": "3",
    "expires": 1567653608019
  }
]
```

I want to remove this entire array when timestamp from expires is equal to current timestamp. How can I do this?

Comment: Your question and the accepted answer do not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let list = [
{
    ytChannel: "xxx",
    startAmount: "1",
    minGrowth: "2",
    maxGrowth: "3",
    expires: 1567653608019
  }
];

setInterval(
  () => (list = list.filter(item => item.expires < Date.now())),
  100
);
```

Comment: That is not deleting the list

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [
  {
    "ytChannel": "xxx",
    "startAmount": "1",
    "minGrowth": "2",
    "maxGrowth": "3",
    "expires": 1567653608019
  }
]

const t = new Date;
arr = arr[0].expires <= t.getTime() ? undefined : arr;
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: That is not deleting the arr

Comment: Behind the logic,you can do anything.However, edited as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how it is defined

Assuming an environment with a `window` scope

```js
window.arr = [
  {
    "ytChannel": "xxx",
    "startAmount": "1",
    "minGrowth": "2",
    "maxGrowth": "3",
    "expires": 1567653608019
  }
]
const now = new Date();
const ex = new Date(arr[0].expires); // for display purpose
console.log(now, ex, now >= ex)
console.log(window.arr)
if (now.getTime() >= arr[0].expires) delete window.arr;
console.log(window.arr)
```